# Image is not properly uploading to Google Cloud storage using GAE php

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload image from Google App Engine using PHP. Image is getting uploaded to proper cloud storage bucket path, but it is not accessible as it contains error. When I am uploading 800kb size image, it is showing 12 byte to cloud storage. I've also tried to upload 1kb size file, even though it is showing 12 byte size. I am not getting the exact issue. 
Here is my code for uploading image to google cloud storage:

```
$file_name = $_FILES['filetoUpload']['name'];
$temp_name = $_FILES['filetoUpload']['tmp_name'];
$type = $_FILES['filetoUpload']['type'];
$options = array('gs' => array('entity' => 'allUsers', 'role' => 'READER', 'acl' => 'public-read', 'Content-Type' => $type, 'contentEncoding' => 'ANSI'));
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$publicFileText = date('ymdhis');
$fileName = "gs://<bucket-name>/" . $file_name;

file_put_contents($fileName, $publicFileText, 0, $context);
$publicUrl = CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl($fileName, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not uploading the image file.  You are just uploading `$publicFileText`, which is a string.

Comment: What i need to pass at $publicFileText ? i am already passing $fileName as a first parameter.

Comment: try: `file_put_contents($fileName, $_FILES['filetoUpload'], 0, $context);`

Comment: Try: `$_FILES['filetoUpload']['tmp_name']`.  Post your log results if that doesn't work.